# git, vimdiff and dirdiff

Tags: git, vim, vimdiff

I'm trying to use vimdiff+[dirdiff.vim](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=102) to diff inside Vim multiple files versionned with Git.

For Mercurial, it is possible with [mercurial extdiff](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/ExtdiffExtension) extension.

The only way I found on the web to integrate Vim with Git diff is to use vimdiff on a singe file, as describe in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3713765/viewing-all-git-diffs-with-vimdiff).

Does any one know how to use vimdiff+dirdiff+git?

Comment: see also git difftool --dir-diff --tool=vimdiff (since v1.7.11)

Comment: related: https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/778/how-to-diff-and-merge-two-directories

Answer (score 19):

## Before git version 1.7.11

`git-diffall` is what I need, thanks a lot. With help of this [page](http://jeetworks.org/node/90) about git difftool and this [one](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/ExtdiffExtension) about running vim+dirdiff from command line, I wrote my `$HOME/.gitconfig` as:

```
[diff]
  tool = default-difftool

[difftool "default-difftool"]
  cmd = vim -f '+next' '+execute \"DirDiff\" argv(0) argv(1)' $LOCAL $REMOTE

[difftool]
  prompt = false
```

After putting  `git-diffall`  in my `PATH`, I can diff for example working directory with branch `dev` with:

```
git diffall dev
```

The `--copy-back` is also what I need if I want to modify the working directory persitantly from Vim:

```
git diffall --copy-back dev
```

## Since git version 1.7.11

Since version [1.7.11](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/Documentation/RelNotes/1.7.11.txt), "git difftool" learned the "--dir-diff" option that simplify things and `git-diffall` is no longer needed.

`.gitconfig` contains:

```
[diff]
  tool = default-difftool
[difftool "default-difftool"]
  cmd = vim -f '+next' '+execute \"DirDiff\" argv(0) argv(1)' $LOCAL $REMOTE '+syntax off'
```

And diffing for example working directory with branch `dev` is done with:

```
git difftool -d dev
```

Comment: +1 for the `cmd`. Adding this comment instead of a new answer so maybe you could update this answer with the following information and accept it for future reference. As @VonC already noted, you can now use `git difftool -d` to diff the entire directory. Your `cmd` will launch you straight into vim's `DirDiff` where everything will work as expected. You **no longer** need `git-diffall`, and the `prompt=false` config line is not necessary when using `-d` with `git difftool`.

Comment: Note: `git diffall` is being removed for git 2.0.X/2.1: see http://stackoverflow.com/a/24979228/6309

Answer (score 6):

Tim Pope's [fugitive](https://github.com/tpope/vim-fugitive) is the quintessential git plug-in for vim. It might not have dirdiff's functionality, but it does integrate `git status` output beautifully, with key mappings to easily navigate between modified files. Any files listed in your `git status` output can then easy be diffed with the <kbd>D</kbd> mapping, allowing you to customise the exact changes going into your changes.

Comment: Thank, I experiment a little with fugitive, I'll try more soon

Answer (score 3):

It would be interesting to monitor the [commits for the Vim module fugitive](https://github.com/tpope/vim-fugitive/commits/master), because, starting with ([git 1.7.11](https://github.com/tpope/vim-fugitive/commits/master), June 2012), **git now can diff directories** (ie display all the files to be compared, before opening the `difftool`)

See "[`git difftool` to give directory compare?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2115188/6309)"

So adding that feature to [`fugitive.vim`](https://github.com/tpope/vim-fugitive/blob/master/plugin/fugitive.vim) would be an evolution from a file to file diff approach.

However, [Zyx](https://stackoverflow.com/users/273566/zyx) points out in the comment the limits of that approach:

> All you need to get this working is:
>
> 1. `git diff --name-status` and
> 2. `git cat-file`,
>
> nothing more (except for some `vimscript` code).
>   And, unlike `git difftool`, this works for any VCS with vcs `diff` and vcs `cat-file` support

Zyx mentions as an example of that file-byfile approach his project [**aurum**](https://bitbucket.org/ZyX_I/aurum):

> My aurum has dirdiff-like functionality (`AuVimDiff full` opens a bunch of tabs with `vimdiff` view of files that have differences) and it never used any sort of `difftool` support.

(See script [`aurum / autoload / aurum / vimdiff.vim`](https://bitbucket.org/ZyX_I/aurum/src/6a934bcf0f60/autoload/aurum/vimdiff.vim))

Zyx adds:

> it cannot be a good guide for a person that wants to add this functionality to fugitive:
>   Actual `git diff --name-status` call is hidden inside the git driver in a function called by `s:git.status` accessed as `repo.functions.status` (because mercurial uses `hg status -r rev1:rev2`, not `hg diff --name-status` and I find this rather logical).
>   Thus you have to traverse three levels of abstraction here (repository interface, shell commands wrapper and only then actual git call).
>   It is faster to write everything from scratch

Comment: My [aurum](https://bitbucket.org/ZyX_I/aurum) has dirdiff-like functionality (`AuVimDiff full` opens a bunch of tabs with vimdiff view of files that have differences) and it never used any sort of difftool support. All you need to get this working is 1. `git diff --name-status` and 2. `git cat-file`, nothing more (except for some vimscript code). And, unlike `git difftool`, this works for *any* VCS with `vcs diff` and `vcs cat-file` support.

Comment: And currently fugitive does not use difftool for anything.

Comment: @ZyX: very interesting. I have included the reference to your m`aurum` project in the answer for more visibility.

Comment: I have to say that though the script you pointed out works, it cannot be a good guide for a person that wants to add this functionality to fugitive: actual `git diff --name-status` call is hidden inside the git driver in a function called by `s:git.status` accessed as `repo.functions.status` (because mercurial uses `hg status -r rev1:rev2`, not `hg diff --name-status` and I find this rather logical). Thus you have to traverse three levels of abstraction here (repository interface, shell commands wrapper and only then actual `git` call). It is faster to write everything from scratch.

Comment: @ZyX understood. I have include your last comment in the answer in order to make that more visible.

Answer (score 2):

Git does not support directory diffs directly, but it can be done with 3rd party extension.

Check out [`git diffall`](https://github.com/thenigan/git-diffall) (disclosure: I wrote this script).  This script works with the tool set by `git config diff.tool <TOOL>` to perform a true directory diff.

Also, see these related questions:

- [git difftool, open all diff files immediately, not in serial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1220309/git-difftool-open-all-diff-files-immediately-not-in-serial)
- [Getting Beyond Compare to Diff 2 Branches Simultaneously](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3365933/getting-beyond-compare-to-diff-2-branches-simultaneously)

Comment: Note: I see you finally removed that script: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24979228/6309