# Using vim as git difftool

Tags: git, vim, diff, vimdiff

I've configured Vim as git difftool in .gitconfig

```
[diff]
    tool = vimdiff
```

If there are changes in N files, i have to close vim (:qa) to see the next diff.

How do i navigate to the next/previous diff without quitting vim?

Comment: does this help you? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8156493/git-vimdiff-and-dirdiff

Comment: Fugitive D command was helpful. Thanks

Comment: What version of Git do you use?

Answer (score 6):

There is no way to tell vimdiff to go to the next file, because `git difftool` invocates vimdiff for each diff file.

So when you end vimdiff with `qa`, `git diff` executes vimdiff again with the next file. From vimdiff's perspective there is no next diff file.

You can suppress the prompt for launching vimdiff, which makes it less annoying:

`git config --global difftool.prompt false`

But, as you already found out yourself, the vim plugin [vim-fugitive](https://github.com/tpope/vim-fugitive) is the way to go. This excellent plugin offers various commands for diffing and merging.

Answer (score 0):

Found this helper script useful (not mine). https://gist.github.com/Osse/4709787

Download the script and set executable permissions.

```
❯ git config --global difftool.vimtabdiff.cmd '~/path/to/vimtabdiff.zsh $LOCAL $REMOTE'
```

And set an alias

```
❯ git config --global alias.dt 'difftool --tool vimtabdiff --dir-diff'
```

Now, the the files with differences each open in a new tab with `git dt`

`]c` and `[c` to move to next and previous diffs within the file. `gt`, `gT` to move to next and previous file.