# How to make "git difftool --dir-diff" working with vim

Tags: git, vimdiff, difftool

I am happy working with `git difftool --dir-diff` with beyond compare to show overall diff across directories and files and navigate through them.

However when it comes to vimdiff, seems it do not support dir diff from git. A git alias I created is as the following

```
    dirdiff = difftool --ignore-submodules --tool=vimdiff --dir-diff --no-symlinks
```

After I do things like `git dirdiff HEAD~1 HEAD`, it list my 2 directories on left and right with vim built in `netrw` file browser. However, press enter on any of them don't make folder expanded on both sides, not to mention open a file with side by side diff.

vimdiff works fine for showing single file diff in visual mode, is there a way to make it also works for `--dir-diff`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find a solution from another [stackoverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8156493/git-vimdiff-and-dirdiff). The answer is provided by @user744629. Following his suggestion

- install [vim dirdiff](https://github.com/will133/vim-dirdiff)
- add the following configuration in `.gitconfig`

```
[alias]
    dirdiff = difftool --ignore-submodules --dir-diff --no-symlinks --tool=vimdirdiff

[difftool "vimdirdiff"]
    cmd = vim -f '+next' '+execute \"DirDiff\" argv(0) argv(1)' $LOCAL $REMOTE
```

After that you can use `git dirdiff HEAD HEAD~1` to view side by side diff.