# How to disable NERDTree when the DirDiff plugin is in use

Tags: vim

I've just started using the [NERDTree](https://github.com/preservim/nerdtree) vim plugin and am generally pleased with it. I also sometimes use the [DirDiff](https://github.com/will133/vim-dirdiff) plugin. My most frequent use of the DirDiff plugin is for git diff via [this stack overflow explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8163934/629530).

I'd like to configure NERDTree to be automatically closed when the DirDiff plugin in effect. Is this possible via my `.vimrc`? I install these plugins via [vim-plug](https://github.com/junegunn/vim-plug).

Answer (score -1):

You can create a custom function that triggers DirDiff and uses `:NERDTreeClose` as dependency and bind that custom function to keymap that you using for DirDiff.

You can also try to play around with `autocmd BufEnter`.

I remember this was my problem as well, if you find solution combining my suggestion please post it here.

Comment: Is that an answer or a comment?

Comment: It's more or less 95% of the solution.